# IOPsciences and a missing reference

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

My university has a subscription at IOPSciences
I am interesting in this article: Galochkin A.I. (1984): On estimates, unimprovable with respect to height, of some linear forms. Mat. Sb. 124 (166), 416-430. English transl.: Math. USSR, Sb. 52, 407-419.

So I went to IOPsciences site to download it (the english version !!) But it looks like IOPSciences did a mistake about this journal. This article does not exist in their data base. Can anyone manage to download this article.

I wrote to IOPSciences but I received no answer.

Comment: there is no english translation available online, but the russian original can be downloaded from http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=2059&option_lang=eng -- you might just feed this to an online translator...

Comment: I agree with Carlo.  *MathSciNet* does not list a translation for that paper, and usually their listings are complete.  @CarloBeenakker ... last time I tried an online translator for a technical math paper, the results were not good.  Admittedly, that was some years ago.

Comment: I also agree with @CarloBeenakker: even the Turpion service redirects to the IOP one, so there's no hope to get it from these standard sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure a machine translation of the [paper](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=2059&option_lang=eng) from russian into english will be sufficient. For starters, I fed two paragraphs on pages 417-418 to https://deepl.com, with the following output (unedited, the only changes I made were to LaTeX the symbols):

---

> The top and bottom estimates in Korobov's paper, as well as in the
> present paper, differed by a constant. Apparently, there are no other
> nontrivial examples of systems consisting of more than two numbers for
> linear forms from which the top and bottom estimates would be so close
> to each other. For linear forms (8), except for the case discussed in
> [5], the top estimates of only $C_2H^{-s}$ were known. These estimates
> are derived by means of the Dirichlet principle and do not take into
> account the specificity of function (1).
>
> The method of proving the theorem will be partially based on the
> effective construction of the system of linear approximation forms
> [3]. However, here the system of approximating forms will be $s$ times
> more "dense," and compared to previous works, the process of exclusion
> will be changed.
>
> The method applied allows us to effectively find all primitive forms
> for which (10) holds for $H>H_0(C_2,a,b,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_s)$.